# delete files based on filenames from array

Tags: arrays, bash, delete-file

Trying to write a bash script that deletes files based on names from an array that's read from a separete file.

I include the file for the array in the script; delete_files.inc
and it seems to populate the arrays just fine, but when I try to delete files from the folder structure I keep getting error "command not found"

```
function get_array() {
    array=() # Create array
    while IFS= read -r line # Read a line
    do
        array+=("$line") # Append line to the array
    done < "$1"
}


get_array ${file_cc}
for file in "${array[@]}"
do
    if [ $delete -eq 1 ]; then
        find ${startdir} -type f -name "$line" -exec rm -f {} 2>/dev/null \;
      else

        echo  "Would've deleted: ${files[@]}"
    fi
done
```

I keep getting the following errors:

```
home/<user>/bin/delete_files.inc: line 19: *.pdf: command not found
```

and every other filename in the array with the same error. Line 19 is just one example.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  We cannot test as presented.  Other points, what is the value of `$delete`?  Which line is no.19?  From the inc file or in the code?  Print your array to ensure it is what you expect.  Then work on the loop.

Comment: What does the array file look like? What happens when you hard-code the list into the script? Are you sure you aren't getting `$line` and `$file` mixed up?

Comment: Which is line 19? In what you posted, it's the `done`, but that makes no sense at all (and you don't show what sets `file_cc`, `delete`, or `startdir`), so I'm pretty sure something's been left out. Your variables are also inconsistent (the main loop sets `file`, but then you use `$line` inside it). Please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem. Also, adding `set -x` before the problem section would probably show what's going on.

Comment: `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array <"$1"` would fill your array without looping through each line of the file.

Comment: Your question is tagged [bash], you should use`readarray` or `mapfile` (they are synonymous) to fill you array from a file.

Comment: Ok. Full code here: https://pastebin.com/5ZQNFAQa

Comment: And the delete_file is here: https://pastebin.com/dFufE1eW
the two first lines are with a " the rest not as You can see